# What is Caddyfile file type?

Tags: intellij-idea, caddyfile

I'm using PhpStorm to develop a project.

I have created a Caddyfile to configure my caddy server.

But PhpStorm doesn't format or highlight the code of the Caddyfile.

I know that I can [change the File Type](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-registering-file-types.html#associate-files-with-ide) for specific file but I don't know which File Type I should choose for Caddyfile.

What is Caddyfile File type in intellij idea?

Comment: I don't think that Caddyfile can be associated with a known file type in IntelliJ IDEA, based on their documentation: https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/concepts. There's also no feature request to support it, so feel free to be the first at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue

Comment: It's currently marked as "won't fix": https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-22098

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-22098, Jetbrains do not plans to support Caddyfile syntax natively.

So I created a [custom FileType](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-registering-file-types.html#create-new-file-type) like so:

[image]

List of keywords (taken from [Caddyfile directicves](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives#caddyfile-directives))

```
abort
acme_server
basicauth
bind
encode
error
file_server
forward_auth
handle
handle_errors
handle_path
header
import
invoke
log
map
method
metrics
php_fastcgi
push
redir
request_body
request_header
respond
reverse_proxy
rewrite
root
route
skip_log
templates
tls
tracing
try_files
uri
vars
```

Result look like this:

[image]

Might be possible to create a plugin to support the [Caddyfile concept](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/concepts) and add it to https://plugins.jetbrains.com/